# Required Field without Submit button after Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to have my all my text/email input forms have a required attribute before you can "Submit" The email

But since I am using some Ajax to keep the page from refreshing after pressing the button the `required` attribute will not work.

This is why I am asking for an alternative for required with Javascript or jQuery (trying to prevent email form spam).

HTML (FORM)

```
<form id="contact">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Voornaam*</label>
        <input name="fn" type="text" class="form-control" id="fn" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Achternaam*</label>
        <input name="ln" type="text" class="form-control" id="ln" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email-address*</label>
        <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="email" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="message">Bericht*</label>
        <textarea name="message" required class="form-control" id="message" rows="6"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="button" onClick="doIets(); this.form.reset();" 
            name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Verstuur  <span id="result"></span></button>
    <div id="result2"></div>
</form>
```

Ajax script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function doIets()
{
       console.log("doe iets");

       var data = {
             ck: (new Date()).getTime(),
         fn: $("#fn").val(),
         ln: $("#ln").val(),
         email: $("#email").val(),
         message: $("#message").val()
      };

      $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "sendmail.php",/*php file path*/
         data: data,
          beforeSend: function(){
           $('#result').html('<img src="loader" style="height:10px;"/>')
          },
         success: function(data){
            $('#result').hide();
            $('#result2').html(data);
         }
         });
      }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use e.preventDefault() when they click on the submit button and then validate the form and after that submit it using the ajax call you created above.

Comment: For example, in JS you would need something like this, if you use jQuery:
`$("#submit").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
//run validation code here
doIets();
});`

You would need to remove the onClick attribute form the HTML. In terms of the validation code, you would need to check that the inputs which have required attribute also have content in them.

Answer (score 0):

since you already read out the data, you can check whether your message is long enough for you via

```
data.message.length
```

if it is 0 (or lower than a threshold you defined), you can skip the ajax call and return some info to the user.

You might also want to trim the message first in order to be sure there aren't only whitespace in there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is part from my code, where I bind the submit event to my form and check by looping if any required field is empty or if I want to do any such thing.

This way may help you--

```
  $('.form .contact-form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.form .message').eq(0).html("<i>Sending... Please Wait...</i>");

    var form = $(this);
    var validated = true;

    $('input[type="text"]',this).each(function(){
      if($(this).val().length < 1){
        $(this).addClass('error').focus();
        validated = false;
        return false;
      }
    });

    if(validated === true){
      $.post(__asyn.ajaxurl, $('.form form').eq(0).serialize(), function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
        console.log(data);      

        });
    }


  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the `event` object to your handler `onClick="doIets(event);`
and then add

```
function doIets(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    ...
}
```

Comment: It still sends an email whenever i press the button

Comment: sorry, i forgot parentess

Comment: Still sends the Email